# Display button as pressed on hold in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to show some icon buttons with green or red color, the problem is as long as they are not pressed they will be displayed as you see on the right two buttons. When pressed is being set as true like `pressed="true"`, it won't do the trick, since the button is selected but not pressed.

here is a picture that explains what I mean:

[image]

I guess there must be an easy way to do that, or not? There must be something which I can set in button and it shows the button how it would be displayed when it is pressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Button has **type** property with a predefined set of values: you can use "Accept" for green and "Reject" for red. Remember though that colors depend on theme. See in the code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="description" content="UI5 table example with local JSON model" />
 <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
 <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>
 
<style>
.MyAcceptButton.sapMBtn span.sapMBtnInner.sapMBtnAccept {
    background-color: Gold;
}
  
.MyAcceptButton.sapMBtn:hover>.sapMBtnHoverable.sapMBtnAccept:not(.sapMBtnActive) {
    background-color: GoldenRod;
  }
  
.MyAcceptButton.sapMBtn:not(.sapMBtnDisabled)>span.sapMBtnInner.sapMBtnAccept.sapMBtnActive {
    background-color: Orange;
  }  
</style>
      
      <title>UI5 Button Example</title>
 
  <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' type='text/javascript'
  src='https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
  data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
  data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m,sap.ui.core'></script>

  <script>
          
          var  oHBox = new sap.m.HBox({ width: "100%" });
          
          // Create Button with specific color scheme via custom style
          // Gold color for normal background
          // GoldenRod for background when mouse hovering
          // Ornage for a pressed button
          
          var oAcceptButton = new sap.m.Button({ icon: "sap-icon://history", type: "Accept" });
          oAcceptButton.addStyleClass("MyAcceptButton");
          
          oHBox.addItem(oAcceptButton);
          oHBox.addItem(new sap.m.Button({ icon: "sap-icon://history", type: "Accept"}));
          oHBox.addItem(new sap.m.Button({ icon: "sap-icon://history", type: "Reject"}));
          
          oHBox.placeAt("content");
  </script>
 </head>
 <body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
 </body>
</html>
```

There is also a ToggleButton, see [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.ToggleButton/preview). It also has **type** property, so you can change its color.

Comment: okay is there a way I can use just for those 2-3 buttons a different theme? because on the rest webpage I am using the sap-belize theme which looks better

Comment: You can define your own css class in a separate css file and add this class to buttons via **class** property.

Comment: could you provide an example ?  would be nice for me

Comment: See updated snippet: added yellow button with a custom style